# Cannot access BIOS/boot menu after installing Windows 10 1903

Tags: windows-10, bios

I recently installed Windows 10 1903 (about six months ago) and I wanted a Linux partition but I've noticed that ever since I installed Windows 10 1903 I can't access my BIOS anymore during boot.

I've hit every key (F2, F11, F8, DEL, numpad-DEL), tried holding them down, repeatedly hitting them, it always just boots to Windows.

My motherboard is an MSI 870 G45 which is quite old but I never had any trouble accessing the BIOS/boot menu before. Even prior versions of W10 didn't do this.

I disabled fast startup in Windows 10 and even tried that advanced restart option where it puts you on a Windows 10 blue screen with a bunch of options, yet there is just no "BIOS Options" option for me. Nothing that allows me to access the BIOS.

Is there any way to prevent Windows from booting temporarily so I can have access to startup options? Ideally I would like to not have to open up the case and mess around with the computer's innards.

It seems insane to me that Windows can just prevent me from accessing basic hardware options. This is borderline malware.

Comment: Have you tried disconnecting the disk drive? It wouldn't be *much* messing around with the innards.

Comment: "Is there any way to prevent Windows from booting temporarily so I can have access to startup options?" - If you cause Windows to not boot 3 times in a row you will enter Advanced Startup.  However, you indicated the Firmware option isn't there, so I am not sure if that will do any good.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I could but this wouldn't achieve much, the goal is to be able to create a secondary boot partition on that drive.

Comment: Often "cold" boot or full power down, unplug power, push power switch for 10 sec or so just to drain all left over power. Then boot and immediately press correct key to get into UEFI/BIOS.

Comment: Disable hibernation in W10, you should be able to get into the bios now.